How to make a fluid stay still inside an object?
I would like to fill a bathtub with water and have the water stay still, starting from frame 1. The only way I know is to drop the fluid into the bathtub and wait for it to stay still (this takes a long time, baking, and the water will never be 100% still).
This can also be applied to a sea, where godzilla comes out from under the water, but the water is still and calm before coming out.
Thanks in advance.


EDIT SOLVED:
Thank you so much, this really worked! The water stayed still and only started flowing when I moved the tub! Again, thank you so much for your help, your screenshots were incredibly helpful too!


If you want a liquid to settle a bit before the animation starts, you can bake the simulation starting some time before the actual animation range  which you have set for rendering by setting Cache > Frame Start to a negative value. However this means that you have to bake a longer simulation, and you could get the same effect by starting to simulate "normally" on frame 1 and just begin rendering on a later frame.
But, you do not have to drop your liquid into the Domain. If your Flow object is placed at the bottom of the Domain and exceeds its boundaries, the water will not fall down and is cut off by the boundaries:

Now the water will only be simulated in the intersection of Domain and Flow and it looks like this - this is a 50 frame animation with absolutely no "settling", just right off simulated from frame 1 on:

Let's say you want to fill something like a bath tub or similar. I created an object with the bath tub cavity and a bit of space around it. This object will be the Effector:

Similar to the Flow exceeding the Domain boundaries in the earlier example, the Flow now has to exceed the boundaries of the tub cavity. But to make sure there will be no water outside the tub, the Flow object has to stay within the Effector object:

The water will now only appear in the cavity, everything that is inside the Effector will not become liquid (therefore it is important that the Effector's face normals are oriented correctly so that Blender knows what is inside and outside). The result looks like this, I just rendered the liquid and disabled the bath tub. The resolutions of the Domain and the Effector were not very high so it does not look great, this is just for a quick demonstration. Again a 50 frame animation with no previous settling of the liquid:


Thank you so much, this really worked! The water stayed still and only started flowing when I moved the tub! Again, thank you so much for your help, your screenshots were incredibly helpful too!
